# How to debug this C program for large inputs?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t, w;
    long int n, m, c, i, j, f = 0;
    long long int b, s = 1;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(w = 1; w <= t; w++)
    {
        f = 0;
        s = 1;
        scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&n,&m,&c);
        b = (long long int) n * m;

        if (c > b) {
            printf("%d\n",0);
        } else {
            for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                for(j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                    s = i * j;
                    if (s == c) {
                        f++;
                        s = 1;
                    }
                }
                printf("%ld\n",f);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When inputs are:

```
1
1000000
1000000
1000000
```

But in output, it does not showing the value of f. Why output is not showing the value of f? Is there any problem related to data types I have used?

Comment: You seriously named your variables `t, w, n, m, c, i, j, f, b, s`???  How in the  world are we supposed to understand the meaning of this code?

Comment: `long` is generally a 32bit data type, so +/- 2147483647. you're way past that with `1000000000000`. you probably want `long long`, which should be 64bit.

Comment: so how can i get that? @MarcB

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the inconvenience @abelenky

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that printf("%ld\n",f); will show the value of f. So, you should a) tell us, what output you expect for a particular input and b) rename the variables, so that we can understand, what you're actually meaning.

Comment: yes it's showing the value of f only when n,m,c<=10000

Answer (score 1):

At least this part seems suspicious.

You wrote:

```
if(s==c)
    f++;
    s=1;
```

Because of your indentation, I think you are trying to write:

```
if(s==c)
{
    f++;
    s=1;
}
```

But what you actually wrote is:

```
if(s==c)
{
    f++;
}
s=1;
```

Based on your indentation, I am guessing that is not what you intended.

Comment: if there is only one statement within the body of if, then there is no need of {}.

Comment: abelenky knows that. (S)he wrote "suspicious"

Comment: but there is nothing suspicious  there..

Comment: Every professional coding standard requires brackets on ALL if-statements.  Even though the language says they are optional for a single statement, it is extremely error prone and unprofessional to omit them.

Comment: True, but whatever code block `s=1;` is supposed to be in, it is useless, since the value of `s` is not further used.

Comment: please try to answer my question @WeatherVane

Comment: @AkashBera please direct your comment to the poster of this unhelpful answer. I cannot answer, for the same reason that abelenky posted in the very first comment at the top of the page, altough (s)he tried.

Comment: You haven't read enough professional coding standards, I'm afraid.  Not all coding standards for C require braces everywhere (though many do).